# Android app crashes when login button clicked (happen only in tablet mode)

Tags: android-studio

I have a project everything works fine except when I clicked on the login button in all tablet mode it will crashes, but it works fine on all non-tablet device.

Here's the logcat in tablet mode:

```
Unsupported class loader
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
        at com.test.signinorup.Login_Fragment.test_initViews(Login_Fragment.java:186)
        at com.test.signinorup.Login_Fragment.onCreateView(Login_Fragment.java:154)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
```

Seeking for advise

Answer (score 0):

The logcat answers your problem, SignInButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button, maybe use wrong cast in findViewById or you are binding your SiggInButton with other button id in your xml file

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. I manage to find the root cause now, seem there are a lot problem in large size xml.